# "Repeat" in Chinese

Tags: translation

I have do not speak Chinese and need to know what the verb (as an instruction) "**repeat**" means.
I'd like to use it when asking someone to repeat what I say just after me. I wish to use the verb "**repeat**" as it is to make it as simple as possible.
Thanks in advance..
Cheers.

Comment: 請跟我重複說一遍 means "please repeat what I say"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Repeat" in Chinese is '重复'(repeat *an action*) or '复述'(repeat *a speech*)

However, if you just say "复述", It would sound too blunt. To be polite, you could say: "请复述(一次)" - "please repeat (once)"

Please notice, the term "复述" is very literary. The colloquial way to say "please repeat" is "请跟着再说一遍" (please follow and repeat/ please repeat it)

- If you want to say: "please repeat after me" you can say "请跟着我再说一遍" (please follow me and repeat) or 请复述我說的词句/字句" (Please repeat the words/ word I say)
- If you want to say: "please repeat this words" you can say "请复述这个词句/字句" (please repeat this words/word)

Comment: Thank you very much @tang-ho. 
I guess for me, when I ask someone to repeat after me (as "Please repeat.") "请复述" will be enough, right?

Comment: @Hakan Tilgel Yes "请复述" (please repeat) is enough. "一次" (once) is redundant because "repeat" already implies 'one more time'